# How to reset password for root in arangodb?

Tags: database, arangodb

I'm root and
I forgot it
What can I do now?

I tried to reinstall arangodb, remove all databases but after new installation old password still exist

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
service arangodb3 stop
/usr/sbin/arangod --server.authentication false
```

and then

```
require("@arangodb/users").replace("root", "my-changed-password");
exit
service arangodb3 restart // **VERY IMPORTANT STEP!!!**
//if you don't restart the server everyone can have access to your database
```

Comment: exactly - Once you started the server with disabled authentication, you can change the password. Please mark your own answer as 'accepted' ;-)

Comment: This doesn't work, because `arangosh` is only the client tool, which is not allowed to disable the server's authentication. You have to start the **server** (arangod) with `--server.authentication false`. You don't need this startup option for arangosh, just connect to the server's endpoint and use a blank password.

Comment: but it worked, I changed the password this way (completely new one) and everything works fine, but now I cannot do this again because I have 401: Unauthorized weird...

Comment: It worked because I have arangod stopped and then I run arangosh without authentication - it starts arangod without authentication for me so you are right

Answer (score 7):

Start the server `arangod` with the option `--server.authentication false`. This will disable authentication, so that you can access the databases without password. If you are asked for credentials in arangosh or the web interface, use `root` as username and a blank password. You can then change the password of user `root` (in the web interface: USERS > root > Change Password).

It is advisable to bind the server to `--server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529` and not `0.0.0.0` with authentication turned off, so that no one from outside can access the unprotected database, but only you locally on the server (you can also bind it to a network address, but make sure that the port is not open to the public in that case).

Answer (score 2):

I'm running ArangoDB3 as a service on Ubuntu, and I wasn't able to figure out how to pass the `--server.authentication false` or `--server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529` parameters to the `arangod` process.

I made it work by changing the same values in */etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf*.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:- Stop running instance of arangodb

```
     sudo systemctl stop arangodb3
```

Step 2:- Start arangodb with disabled authentication

```
     sudo /usr/sbin/arangod --server.authentication false
```

Step 3:- Start arango shell in new terminal

```
     arangosh
```

Step 4 :- Change password of root in arango shell

```
     require("@arangodb/users").replace("root", "new-password");
```

Step 5 :- Close arango shell

```
     exit
```

Step 6 :- Stop arangodb unautheticated service in the previous terminal

```
     CTRL + c
```

Step 7 :- Restart arangodb service

```
     sudo systemctl start arangodb3
```